# Better option than Nested Grids, stack panels or wrappanels for DataContext binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I do realize an additional control could also suffice but all of the above seems like using a sledge hammer when all I need is a gentle tap.  Here's my user control and if more information is really needed I can supply the backing viewmodel and model upon request.

Or to put it another way, nesting a grid within a grid just to allow the output contained within the sub-grid (or wrappanel etc) seems excessive in addition to making the UI more difficult than it has to be to maintain consistency without fixed widths.

Using binding paths also seem clumsy although I am aware I could do that as well and if that's the answer so be it.

In service of brevity I have removed all but the actual functional (non visual) xaml..

```
<UserControl DataContext="{ Binding Source={ StaticResource Locator },
                        Path=NestedConfigSample }">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="Feature Teams"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{ Binding FeatureTeams, 
                            UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged }" 
              DisplayMemberPath="FeatureTeamName" 
              SelectedItem="{ Binding SelectedTeam }"/>
    <Grid DataContext="{ Binding SelectedTeam }">
        <Label Content="Sql Database Suffix"/>
        <Label Content="{ Binding SqlDatabaseSuffix }"/>
        <Label Content="Web App Suffix"/>
        <Label Content="{ Binding WebAppSuffix }"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: So what is your **particluar** and **isolated** problem? Does it look bad? Is the performance bad? Is XAML too complex?

Comment: The only problem I see is setting `DataContext` explicitly, but that's my MVVM's fan opinion.

Comment: What's the point of setting the DataContext on the Grid? Why not get rid of it and use Path=SelectedItem.SqlDatabaseSuffix? Using a Grid with a bound DataContext to save a little c&p is just dumb. Having a 2nd grid just to make a DataContext container is also dumb if you aren't using any of the Grid functionality.

Comment: Forest, trees and too much shrubbery.  Setting it explicitly to SelectedItem.Property is the right way to go - and I'm a little embarrassed I did not see it immediately.

Thanks all.

Comment: FYI Sledgehammer I did upvote you and then somehow 'un'upvoted you and it won't allow me to do re-apply my upvote.

So +1 to you?  :\  I fail at technology today.